# android passing data from class to activity

Tags: android, class, android-activity

I have been looking for a long time for a simple way to pass data (string type) from class to activity.

I found some tutorials about passing data from activity to class but is it possible to do the opposite, passing data from class to activity ?

Comment: I think you have to use custom interface for it.

Comment: What do you mean by class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you import the class in your activity (which is also a class by the way) you can easily access the classes attributes.

example: MyClass.java

```
package edu.user.yourappname;

public class MyClass {

  public string infoToPass = "whatever";

}
```

MyActivity.java

```
package edu.user.yourappname;
import edu.user.yourappname.MyClass

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

  String myString = MyClass.infoToPass;

  }

}
```

i have no IDE to type this in atm it might contain some errors :S but i hope you get the idea.
if you need more specific help you have to provide a code sample.
also, what do you want to achieve exactly? maybie there's a different approach.

cheers!

Comment: no problem, also be aware of the different access modifiers if you pass attributes from classes to other classes.
public = Accessible from any class; private = Accessible only from within the same class (or any nested classes); default = Accessible only from the classes in the same package (also known as friendly)

Answer (score 0):

Create Interface and implement that in your activity. Pass the activity instance in your class and and call that instance with interface method whenever you like.

Comment: `Talk is cheap. Show me the code` [^](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/437173-talk-is-cheap-show-me-the-code)

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear, create an interface and use it as following:

```
public interface SomeInterface{
    public void passValue(String value);
}

public SomeActivity extends Activity implements SomeInterface{

    // place any code you want in your activity, onCreate, onResume, etc.

    private void someMethod(){
         // Wherever in your activity, initialize your class with your activity.
         SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(this);
         someClass.someMethod();
    }

    public void passValue(String value){
         // do whatever you want with your value
    }

}

public class SomeClass{

    private SomeInterface someInterfaceInstance;

    public SomeClass(SomeInterface someInterfaceInstance){
        this.someInterfaceInstance = someInterfaceInstance;
    }

    public void someMethod(){

        // Some code...

        someInterfaceInstance.passValue("Hello World!");

        // Some more code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easy way of doing it -

#### By defining static variables

In your class, make the String whose value you want to pass `public static` like this -

```
public static String pass;
```

And then in you activity, you can directly access it since it's a public variable like this -

```
String receive = className.pass;
```